# GWT cellTable with data binding

Tags: gwt, data-binding, celltable

Here's the situation: I have a cellTable, which is filled with objects coming form my server. These objects have a state, which changes over time and I want to reflect that in my cellTable. Is there a way I can update only one row of my cellTable, of do I have to reload **all** of the objects in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply changes to any object in the list that backs your CellTable, and the CellTable will reflect these changes when you call `ListDataProvider#refresh`.